# Erlang - Why cant I use size() of a value when pattern matching a binary?

Tags: erlang

Assigned values,

```
A = <<"hell">>
```

I have two code snippets which should do the same operation,

```
<<A:size(A)/binary, Rest/binary>> = <<"hello">>
```

The above fails with the reason : *syntax error before: '('*

Then I assign value of size(A) to B,

```
B = size(A)
```

Then the following snippet works,

```
<<A:B/binary, Rest/binary>> = <<"hello">>
```

Why wont the first work?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Reference Manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/users_guide.html) [8.17  Bit Syntax Expressions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id8199)

> Used in a bit string construction, `Size` is an expression that is to
>   evaluate to an integer.
>
> Used in a bit string matching, `Size` must be an integer, or a
>   variable bound to an integer.

So even `<<A:(size(A))/binary, Rest/binary>> = <<"hello">>` would be correct syntax, it is not allowed in matching (`illegal bit size`).